# Vim colors not working

Tags: bash, ubuntu, vim, colors, gnome-terminal

I am using xterm 256 on Ubuntu 14.04 lts

I set the coloscheme for mango but as you see in the vim file on the right, unity's colors are overriding the colorscheme. What ever it is the colors arent setting correctly. I have verified 256 color support with python files. $TERM is xterm-256

[image]

Comment: So, `:echo &t_Co` from within VIM reports 256, right? Also, what happens when you set the colorscheme manually after the editor has initialised (eg: `:colorscheme mango`)?

Comment: `xterm-256color` not xterm-256

Comment: yes it is 256 and 'xterm-256color'

Comment: I tried answering this but obviously I don't understand the question.  Perhaps some more detail could be added?  Maybe I'm being dumb but it's not clear what you are asking

Answer (score 1):

Mango.vim is a colour scheme for javascript.  But you are using it for python.

As you can see from this sample on the [Mango github](https://github.com/goatslacker/mango.vim), your above example (of python) is being rendered as well as could be expected.

For example, "def" is in a orange colour

[image]

Comment: Is this gvim or terminal emulator? You can see that my background was completely different regardless of language. At least that should've been the same.